# Adding values to a LIST from a different class then using the added values in another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I create the list and initialize here .

```
public class Variables
        {
            private List<string> suitable = new List<string>();
            public List<string> GetList()
            {
                return suitable;
            }
        }
```

I save some Value to the List here . PS When i print the list , it works fine .

```
     private void{
                
            Variables variables = new Variables();
            List<string> savedsuit = variables.GetList();

            foreach (_Excel.Range cell in rangematerial.Cells)
            {
                string value = (cell.Value2).ToString();
                if (distinct.Add(value))
                    savedsuit.Add(value);


            }
        }
        savedsuit.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0}\t", i));
```

I then try to use the saved values from the list in a Switch case block below , i dont get an error ,but it doesn't work.

Did i miss something ?

What i need it to do is add add an Item to ComboBox25 only if the item is both in **candidate/s** and **suitable**

```
private void{               

        Variables variables = new Variables();
        List<string> usesuit = variables.GetList();             
        string material = "PN16";

        switch (material)
        {
            case "PN16":
            case "PN25":
            case "CL150":
                //Add only if item in the LIST suitable:
                comboBox25.Items.Clear();
                var candidates = new[] { "ASTM A395/DIN 0.7043", "ASTM A216/DIN 1.0619", "ASTM A351/DIN 1.4408" };
                foreach (var c in candidates.Where(x => usesuit.Contains(x)))
                    comboBox25.Items.Add(c);
                break;
            case "PN40":
            case "PN63":
            case "PN100":
            case "CL300":
            case "CL600":
                //Add only If in the List
                comboBox25.Items.Clear();
                var candidates2 = new[] { "ASTM A216/DIN 1.0619", "ASTM A351/DIN 1.4408" };
                foreach (var c in candidates2)
                    if (usesuit.Contains(c))
                        comboBox25.Items.Add(c);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Variables variables = new Variables();` - this creates a new instance of the class `variables`. An analogy would be this: You buy two Aston Martin DB9 cars, and you place a suitcase in the trunk of the first car (car A). You then open the trunk of the second car (car B) and look for your suitcase. Of course, being a different car, it's not going to contain your suitcase. It's the same with instances of classes. You either need to pass the instance of the class from one form to the other, or you need to make the class `static` (which sort of makes one global instance for your application).

Comment: This actually really helped ! Thank you for not being condescending like most!